# Flutter - Getting wrong version package with version constraints

Tags: flutter, dart, version

`my_base` is my private package.

I publish version to `1.0.5` and the version constraints are shown below

```yaml
my_base: 
  version: ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0"
  hosted:
    url: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/
```

When running `flutter pub upgrade`, it shows:

```
...
my_base 1.0.1 (was 1.0.0) (1.0.5 available)
...
```

I modify version `1.0.0` to `1.0.2` and run `flutter pub upgrade` again, it works

```yaml
my_base: 
  version: ">=1.0.2 <1.1.0"
  hosted:
    url: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/
```

```bash
...
my_base 1.0.5 (was 1.0.1)
...
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The constraint allows `1.0.5` to be installed actually. So, it tries to install the highest version available below `1.1.0`. Which version you'd like to install?

Comment: @lepsch I want to install `1.0.5`, but it will install `1.0.1` when version constraint is `">=1.0.0 <1.1.0"`

Comment: Try to specify a fixed version like `version: 1.0.5` instead of the open constraint `version: ">=1.0.2 <1.1.0"`

Comment: Yes, it works by sepcifying a fixed version, but i want to understand is why will getting a wrong version with using open constraint. 